# POST Request used but still responseText is not complete.Why?

Tags: javascript, post, xhtml, xmlhttprequest

I am just simply trying to traverse all the div elements in the XHTML here http://www.w3.org/. I copied the HTML into w3c.html and ran the following code.
But the responseText is not complete due to which my code is failing.

I used the GET request  initially and I thought this is the problem(thought it was a problem) but It still didn't solve the issue.

```
function traverseHtml()
{
var xmlhttprequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttprequest.open('POST','w3c.html',false);
xmlhttprequest.send(null);
var respText=xmlhttprequest.responseText;
alert('The ResponseText is '+respText);
/*var xml=(new DOMParser()).parseFromString(respText,'text/xml');
var result=xml.evaluate('//div',xml,null,XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,null);
var node=result.iterateNext();
alert(node);
while(node)
{
alert(node.childNodes[0].nodeName);
node=result.iterateNext()
}
*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use the responseText property right after sending a request. You need to make a function that will be called when it's done, like this:

```
var xmlhttprequest;

xmlhttprequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttprequest.open('GET', 'w3c.html', true);
xmlhttprequest.send();
xmlhttprequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    // Check if request done and it didn't fail
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        alert('The ResponseText is '+xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I am using synchronous mechanism (false) for it.Shouldn't the script wait for open() to return ?

Comment: It should, but it's much better to use the asynchronous mechanism (especially since it allows you to check the progress instead of freezing the browser until it finishes).

Comment: Did you try running your code cause the responseText is still not complete for me on firefox.Further I had to use status code of 0 instead of 200 .
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=331610

Comment: Forget about the status code thing, its 0 only when used without webserver.